# Changed name of form and project stopped working. Help

Tags: c#, file-rename

I have a big project and I changed the name of 1st form from "Form1" to "WebBrowser", now I It gives me following error.

`The type or namespace 'Form1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I cannot even change the name back to Form1. it says cannot find WebBrowser.cs on disk, it is renamed or deleted from the disk. What I should do, I have a submission tomorrow.

Thanks

Comment: Did you double click on the error message to see where in the project it is happening? When you find Form1, change it to WebBrowser

Answer (score 1):

Change every reference for `Form1` to `WebBrowser`.

You can double click on the error in your Error List and change it.

Comment: in project or in solution folder or both

Comment: Now it also says: Unable to create a manifest resource name for "WebBrowser.resx". Could not find file 'C:\Documents and Settings\default\Desktop\C#\web_browser\web_browser\WebBrowser.cs'. web_browser

Comment: Delete the current form and try creating a new form with the same name  and copy all the contents to the new form.